# Load bitmap from project resources

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

I want to change some pixels of an image. The image build action is set to "Resource". I'm not possible to get a Bitmap object, so I can make my changes with the for loop below.

```
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("pack://application:,,,/ovl_kommen.png");


        //Change Black pixels to color
        for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            {
                if (bmp.GetPixel(x,y) == System.Drawing.Color.Black)
                {
                    bmp.SetPixel(x, y, System.Drawing.Color.Blue);
                }
            }
        }
```

My next problem is, to view the modified bitmap to an user. I have a WPF image control *img_kommen* which I want to set the bitmap as source.
 `img_kommen.Source = bmp`

Comment: System.Drawing.Bitmap is WinForms, not WPF. You would usually not use it in WPF application.

Comment: Whats the WPF equivalent?

Comment: It's BitmapImage. There also is WriteableBitmap, which allows to modify the pixel buffer.

Comment: Is there any guide/example how to set/getPixel colors of an BitmapImage?

Comment: Why would you want to do that all, instead of just editing the image before using it as a resource?

Comment: It's a simple black icon with transparent background. When the user selects red as foreground, the icon needs to change its black pixels to red.

Comment: WPF provides better ways to accomplish that. You may for example use a Path instead of an Image control, and have a Geometry for the Icon shape. Or put the image into an ImageBrush that is used as the OpacityMask of a Rectangle with an appropriate Fill (i.e. black or red).

Comment: Or simply use two different image resources, one black and one red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manipulating pixel values, better simply use a filled `Rectangle` and apply your icon image as [`OpacityMask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.opacitymask(v=vs.110).aspx), because

> This property only uses whatever the alpha channel value is for the supplied Brush. The other channels of the Brush's rendered content (Red, Green, or Blue) are ignored

Example:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="icon" Fill="Black" Width="100" Height="100">
    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="ovl_kommen.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
</Rectangle>
```

Then set the icon color in code behind like:

```
icon.Fill = Brushes.Red;
```

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you for your help!